# Cant save SQL output to a File in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I been trying this [camel-sql](http://camel.apache.org/sql-example.html) example to fetch some rows from the back-end oracle.

**Datasource definition:**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:port:sid"/>
    <property name="username" value="username"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>
```

**Routes Definition:**

```
<route id="QueryTable">
    <from uri="timer:foo?period=5s"/>
    <to uri="sql:{{sql.selectOrder}}"/>
    <to uri="file:target/data/?fileName=data.txt"/>
</route>
```

It seems to fetch the row properly, but, does not create the file and reports the following exceptions. Any help would be highly appreciated.

> at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:198)
>       at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:105)
>       ... 16 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html

> For select operations, the result is an instance of `List<Map<String, Object>>` type, as returned by the JdbcTemplate.queryForList() method.

You received `List<Map<String, Object>>` as result of the query. If you like to save this results to file, you have to split list by records (use splitter), convert one record to string (maybe you can use some sort of template, or just join to string fields values) and save (append) this string to file.

Comment: And, more generically, advice to a newbie would be: before and after each step in your route, you should know the data-type of the message-body. So: know the data-type before a step (and check it if you don't), so that you can ask if that step can handle that type of body. Also, know the data-type that results from a step 9and check if you don't).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the kind help. Here is what I used to save the resultSet to a file.

```html
<from uri="timer:foo?repeatCount=1" />
    <to uri="sql:{{sql.selectOrder}}"/>
    <marshal>
     <csv delimiter="|" />
    </marshal>
 <to uri="file://target/test.csv?fileName=data.txt" />
```

And of course, pom.xml has to have the following dependency added.

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-csv</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```